# Como verificar si ya existe un libro ingresado

Tags: python

Como hago para verficiar si existe ya el libro ingresado. Ejemplo:

```
 libros = {
        "Principito" : ["Titulo: Principito","Genero: Fantasia", "paginas: 20", "Autor: Raul", "Numero ISBN: 12312123", "AÃ±o de edicion: 1994", "Editorial: IZI"],
         "El padrino" : ["Titulo: El padrino","Genero:Ficcion", "paginas: 30", "Autor: Lopez", "Numero ISBN: 22312312", "AÃ±o de edicion: 1992", "Editorial: PIZI"]
}
```

Me quedo algo asi pero se que esta mal. El error ya se que esta en el if pero como lo tendria que poner?

```
 #Funcion para consultar por un libro.
 def consultar():
      print("Por cual libro desea consultar?")
      s=input()
      if (libros[s] == libros):
            print("Tenemos ese libro en la Biblioteca")
      else:
            print("No tenemos ese libro en la Biblioteca")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay una manera mas optima de realizar esto:

```
libros = {
    "Principito" : ["Titulo: Principito","Genero: Fantasia", "paginas: 20", "Autor: Raul", "Numero ISBN: 12312123", "AÃ±o de edicion: 1994", "Editorial: IZI"],
     "El padrino" : ["Titulo: El padrino","Genero:Ficcion", "paginas: 30", "Autor: Lopez", "Numero ISBN: 22312312", "AÃ±o de edicion: 1992", "Editorial: PIZI"]
}
```

Imaginas que vez del input(), tenemos un parametro de entrada "text", para poder centrarnos en el for.

```py
def consultar1(text="El padrino"):
    existe = 0 
    for libro in libros:
        if text == libro:
            existe = 1
    if (existe == 1):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Esta sería adaptado a la respuesta anterior.

```py
def consultar2(text="El padrino"):
    if text in libros:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Con esto vamos recorriendo todas las claves solo hasta que haya un match, en caso de que haya.

Puedes ver como es mucho mas rápido, y contra mas grande sea tu libros la diferencia será mayor.

```
%timeit -n1000 consultar1(): 1000 loops, best of 3: 623 ns per loop
%timeit -n1000 consultar2(): 1000 loops, best of 3: 302 ns per loop
```

La mitad de tiempo con solo dos entradas.

Answer (score 0):

Según lo que entiendo tu quieres que el usuario ingrese el nombre de un libro y ese buscarlo en la “base de datos” la cual seria el arreglo. Si es así el ejemplo que te dejo te servirá:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#AGREGA TU ARREGLO <-----
#Funcion para consultar por un libro.
def consultar():
      print("Por cual libro desea consultar?")
      s=raw_input()
      existe = 0 
      for libro in libros:
          if s == libro:
              existe = 1

      if (existe == 1):
            print("Tenemos ese libro en la Biblioteca")
      else:
            print("No tenemos ese libro en la Biblioteca")

consultar()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: De nada. Podrias puntear mi respuesta, me serviria para ganar puntos, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Ésta solucion me parece más simple usando el codigo del autor pero "pythonizado":

```
def consultar():
    print("Por cual libro desea consultar?")
    consulta = input()

    if consulta in libros:
        print("Tenemos ese libro en la Biblioteca")
    else:
        print("No tenemos ese libro en la Biblioteca")
```